# Running multiple cmd commands from powershell script as if I was running it in cmd shell

Tags: mongodb, powershell

I am trying to create a powershell script which will create a session in a remote machine and run a series of commands. These commands in question are to drop a Mongodb database before deployment of code.

I have the session side working but when I try to run the cmd I get `X is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`.

The process I take when I am logged into the remote machine and using cmd is:

1. `'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongo.exe'`
2. `use <database>`
3. `db.dropDatabase()`

This works correctly and I am trying to run those in powershell. They need to be run line by line in order to work.

ps1:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "remoteMachine" -Credential $cred

Enter-PSSession -Session $session

Invoke-Command -ComputerName "remoteMachine" -ScriptBlock {
    & 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongo.exe' 
    & 'use <database>'
    & 'db.dropDatabase()'
}

Exit-PSSession
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

When this is run I am getting the following errors:

> The term 'use Assessment' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>
> The term 'db.dropDatabase()' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure it out by looking through `&  'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongo.exe' --help`.

Rather than using multiple lines, I put the command on one line like:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "remoteMachine" -ScriptBlock {
    & 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongo.exe' <database> --eval '<action>'
}
```

For example:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "remoteMachine" -ScriptBlock {
    & 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongo.exe' testDatabase --eval 'db.dropDatabase()'
}
```